# ESLint configuration with typescript jsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, eslint

I am having issues with configuration with typescript. Here is my following code in tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

and here is the error that i am having:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/Components/AdvancedSearch/AdvancedSearch.tsx        Line 80:21:
> 'JSX' is not defined  no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

file causing error AdvancedSearch.tsx:

edit and update full code in AdvancedSearch

```
type AdvancedSearchState = {
  containerHeight: number,
  showMore: boolean,
  transitioning: boolean;
};
type Props = {
  show: boolean;
  // selected: [ContractType];
  selected: any;
  onChange: (e: any) => void;
  contracts: ContractType[];
};
class AdvancedSearch extends React.Component<Props, AdvancedSearchState> {
  advancedSearchContainer: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  advancedSearchWrapper: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
  width: number = 3;
  labelStyle = {
    color: "#1e7e34",
    "text-decoration": "underline"
  };
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.selectItem = this.selectItem.bind(this);
    this.advancedSearchContainer = React.createRef();
    this.advancedSearchWrapper = React.createRef();
    this.resize = this.resize.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      showMore: false,
      containerHeight: 0,
      transitioning: true
    };
  }
  getContainerHeight() {
    let containerHeight = 0;
    if (this.advancedSearchContainer.current) {
      containerHeight = this.advancedSearchContainer.current.clientHeight;
    }
    return containerHeight;
  }
  resize() {
    let containerHeight = this.getContainerHeight();
    if (this.state.containerHeight !== containerHeight) {
      this.setState({ containerHeight: containerHeight });
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ containerHeight: this.getContainerHeight() });
    window.addEventListener("resize", this.resize);
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", this.resize);
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log(this.state.containerHeight);
    this.resize();
  }
  selectItem(name: string) {
    // let selectedContract = name.currentTarget.name;
    // currently change the selectedContract as just the string
    let selectedContract = name;
    let selected = this.props.selected;
    let inx = this.props.selected.indexOf(selectedContract);
    if (inx > -1) {
      selected.splice(inx, 1);
    } else {
      selected.push(selectedContract);
    }
    let event = {
      target: {
        value: selected,
        name: "contracts"
      }
    };
    this.props.onChange(event);
  }
  chunkArray(array: JSX.Element[], width: number) {
    return array.reduce((acc: any[][], item: any, index: number) => {
      let loc = Math.floor(index / width);
      if (!acc[loc]) {
        acc[loc] = [];
      }
      acc[loc].push(item);
      return acc;
    }, []);
  }

  render() {
    //TODO: Should be passed in and not the list of contracts
    let initialList = this.chunkArray(
      this.props.contracts.map(contractType => {
        return (
          <div className="four columns contract-container">
            <span className="contract-header">
              {contractType.contractTypeName}
            </span>
            <dl className="contract-list">
              {contractType.contracts.map(contract => {
                return (
                  <li className="contract">
                    <MvwCheckbox
                      labelStyle={this.labelStyle}
                      onChange={this.selectItem}
                      checked={this.props.selected.indexOf(contract.name) >= 0}
                      label={contract.name}
                      name={contract.name}
                    />
                  </li>
                );
              })}
            </dl>
          </div>
        );
      }),
      this.width
    );
    let list;
    if (this.state.showMore) {
      list = initialList.map((item: React.ReactNode) => {
        return <div className="row">{item}</div>;
      });
    } else {
      list = [initialList[0]].map(item => {
        return <div className="row">{item}</div>;
      });
    }
    return (
      <div
        className={
          "twelve column advanced-search " + (this.props.show ? "show" : "")
        }
      >
        <div
          className="advanced-search-wrapper"
          ref={this.advancedSearchWrapper}
          style={{ height: this.props.show ? this.state.containerHeight : 0 }}
        >
          <div
            className="advanced-search-content"
            ref={this.advancedSearchContainer}
          >
            <div className="advanced-search-body">
              <div className="advanced-search-title">
                <p>
                  Please select the product(s) you wish to use for your
                  Reservation Search:
                </p>
              </div>
              <div className="advanced-search-list">{list}</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default AdvancedSearch;
```

Updated and added import for AdvancedSearch file:

```
import React from "react";
import MvwCheckbox from "../../Generic/MvCheckBox";
import "./AdvancedSearch.css";
import ContractType from "../../Interfaces/AdvanceSearchInterface"
```

Comment: Can someone help me solve this error ?

Comment: Could you share full code of `AdvancedSearch.tsx`?

Comment: @MajidM. just added full code in my post

Comment: Does your code have any `import`?

Comment: Yes just a couple import just added it in

Answer (score 1):

`no-undef` is causing an ESLint/TypeScript compatibility problem in this instance. Check out the [FAQ](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/FAQ.md#i-get-errors-from-the-no-undef-rule-about-global-variables-not-being-defined-even-though-there-are-no-typescript-errors) which mentions your issue specifically. I will just quote the relevant parts here:

> We strongly recommend that you do not use the `no-undef` lint rule on TypeScript projects. The checks it provides are already provided by TypeScript without the need for configuration - TypeScript just does this significantly better.
>
> As of our v4.0.0 release, this also applies to types. If you use global types from a 3rd party package (i.e. anything from an `@types` package), then you will have to configure ESLint appropriately to define these global types. For example; the `JSX` namespace from `@types/react` is a global 3rd party type that you must define in your ESLint config.

See this [ESLint](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/language-options#specifying-globals) guide for help on defining globals. You will need to add a `globals` section to your `.eslintrc` which includes `JSX`:

```
"globals": {
    "JSX": "readonly",
},
```

You can turn `no-undef` off for the project altogether by defining `rules` in your `.eslintrc`:

```
"rules": {
    "no-undef": "off"
}
```

Or you can add an `overrides` section to turn off this rule for typescript files specifically if you have a mixed TS/JS project:

```
"overrides": [
    {
        "files": ["*.ts", "*.tsx"],
        "rules": {
            "no-undef": "off"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: I added all of it in my `.eslint.json` but still having the issues. Any another solution?

Comment: `.eslint.json` is not a valid config file - make sure its `.eslintrc.json`. Share all your ESLint config in the main post if possible.

Comment: It still didn't resolve my error

Comment: @NhanNguyen I just realised this is a base ESLint rule and not actually related to typescript-eslint. See my update to the second code block and try turning off the rule altogether again. If that doesn't work then I think your ESLint is still incorrectly configured with your project.

Answer (score 0):

#### Add JSX property

Add this property in tsconfig.json

```
"jsx": "react-jsx"
```

Comment: I added all of it in my `.eslint.json` but still having the issues. Any another solution?

Comment: @NhanNguyen sorry I meant adding this is in tsconfig.json and please share your ESLint config as well to debug better.

Comment: before I don't have any ESLint config yet.

Comment: But when I added `"jsx": "react-jsx"` my terminal said It have to be `preserve` or `react` or `react-native`